# How to display all the images stored in my MVC folder and their path is in database table using MVC razor?

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

Here is my controller code to save my uploaded image in my application folder ("~/Content/Files") and to store the path in the database table named "imageupload".

my objective is to display all the images stored in the folder ("~/Content/Files") using the path in my database table.

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(prop prop)
        {
            var db = new db_DotnetEntities();
            HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var tbl = new imageupload();
                if (file == null)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please Upload file");
                }
                else if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    int MaxContentLength = 1024 * 1024 * 3;
                    string[] allowedFileExtensions = { ".jpeg", ".png", ".pdf", "gif" };
                    if (!allowedFileExtensions.Contains(file.FileName.Substring(file.FileName.LastIndexOf('.'))))
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Please File of type" + string.Join(",", allowedFileExtensions));
                    }
                    else if (file.ContentLength > MaxContentLength)
                    {
                        ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Your file is too large, maximum allowed size is: " + MaxContentLength + " MB");
                    }
                    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                    var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files"), fileName);
                    tbl.imageurl = fileName;
                    db.imageuploads.Add(tbl);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    file.SaveAs(path);
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "Image Sucessfully Uploaded");

                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Here is My Model

```
public class prop
    {
        public string fileimg { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is My view

```
@model imageMVC.Models.prop

@using (Html.BeginForm("index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    @Html.TextBoxFor(x=>x.fileimg,new{@type="File"})
    <input type="submit" id="submit"/>
}
```

I am using ADO Data Entity Model.

kindly tell me how to write code to display all images stored in ("~/Content/Files").

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `return View(db.imageuploads.ToList())`, and in your view, print the filenames in an `<img src="" />` element? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my Model.I have Added a list Property to takes list of images in the folder ("~/Content/Files")

```
    public class Prop 
        {
            public string Fileimg { get; set; }    
            public IEnumerable<string> Images { get; set; }

        }
```

Here is my ActionResult of controller to Display List of images in folder ("~/Content/Files")

```
  public ActionResult List(Prop obj)
        {
            obj.Images=Directory.EnumerateFiles(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/"))
                .Select(fn => "~/Content/Files/" + Path.GetFileName(fn));
            var objfile = new DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/Content/Files/"));
            var file = objfile.GetFiles("*.*");              
            return View(obj);
        }
```

Here is My View to loop all the images and display all in the view

```
@model imageMVC.Models.Prop

<table style="border: solid">
    <tr>
        <th>IMAGES</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var img in Model.Images)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="@Url.Content(img)"/>
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

All the images in that folder are set in the Model property Images and I am Looping all the images and Displaying it in view.